# Instantiate an object that takes a JPanel parameter using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, nosuchmethoderror, nosuchmethod

I'm trying to instantiate an object `Robot` knowing that the Robot constructor take a JPanel parameter using reflection.

```
Class<?> classRobot = null;
Constructor<?> constructorRobot;
classRobot = Class.forName(fullClassRobots.get(i));
constructorRobot = classRobot.getConstructor(JPanel.class);
robot.add((Robot)constructorRobot.newInstance(panelBattlefield));
```

```
public Robot(JPanel panelBattlefield) { 
...
}
```

My problem is that I keep getting a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is this robot you are talking about is `java.awt.Robot`? If so, `Robot` has no constructor that takes a `JPanel`, see for yourself https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html hence the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`, if `java.awt.Robot` is not what you were talking about, please provide more details as to which `Robot` you are talking about.

Comment: Also, this question looks horribly like an XY problem, here's a link that explains what an XY problem is and how to avoid asking bad questions. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Looks like you want to dynamically instantiate subclasses of `Robot`. Are you sure those subclasses have a constructor that take a single `JPanel` as argument?